# cs-cart 4.2.4 list category list on homepage

Tags: php, smarty, cs-cart

after reinstalling cs-cart 4.2.4 we wanted to list the categories with it's subcategories in a block on the fronted. 
We had this code to do this:

```
<div class="cat-blocks">
    {foreach from=$items item="category"}
        <li class="cat-blocks-item-li">
            <div class="cat-blocks-item-li-wrapper">
                <div class="cat-blocks-item-li-image">
                     <a href="{"categories.view?category_id=`$category.more.category_id`"|fn_url}" class="ty-subcategories-block__a">
                            {if $category.more.main_pair}
                                {include file="common/image.tpl"
                                    show_detailed_link=false
                                    images=$category.more.main_pair
                                    no_ids=true
                                    image_id="category_image"
                                    image_width=235
                                    image_height=220
                                    class="cat-blocks-item-img"
                                }
                            {/if}

                        </a>
                </div>
                <div class="cat-blocks-item-li-name">
                    <h3> <a href="{"categories.view?category_id=`$category.more.category_id`"|fn_url}" class="cat-blocks-item-li-name__a">
                    {$category.more.category}</a></h3>
                    {if $category.sub}
                        <div class="cat-blocks-item-li-subcategories">
                        {foreach from=$category.sub item="sub"}
                            <a href="{"categories.view?category_id=`$sub.category_id`"|fn_url}" class="cat-blocks-item-li-sub__a">
                                {$sub.category}
                            </a>
                        {/foreach}
                        </div>
                    {/if}
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    {/foreach}
</div>
```

After reinstalling the website although the css is ok the block is totally empty and all we are see in firebug is

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/index.php?dispatch=categories.view&amp;category_id=" class="ty-subcategories-block__a"`>
```

What am I missing. 
Can anyone please help ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Please remove **.more** from all variables (category_id, category, main_pair )

## before

```
<a href="{"categories.view?category_id=`$category.more.category_id`"|fn_url}" class="cat-blocks-item-li-name__a">{$category.more.category}</a>
```

## after

```
<a href="{"categories.view?category_id=`$category.category_id`"|fn_url}" class="cat-blocks-item-li-name__a">{$category.category}</a>
```

Comment: Hi, I tried it without success. This is the code after the change. http://pastebin.com/F8b6FGyY

Comment: please check again because you miss a few ;) http://prntscr.com/9masg2 ( all .more ;) )

Answer (score 0):

Please add

```
{$items|fn_print_r}
```

before this line of code:

```
{foreach from=$items item="category"}
```

Then clear cache and check the result. You will see the content of the $items array. Please make sure that each element of this array contains the "category", "category_id" and "main_pair" values.